# PrintTo for a pointer in Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

I can specify how to display the content of an object if a test has failed. To do it, I define the function `PrintTo` for the class. The result is as desired (the string `MyObject as object`):

```
x.cpp:17: Failure
Value of: foo1
Expected: has foo <MyObject as object>
  Actual: <MyObject as object> (of type Foo)
```

Unfortunately, I can't find how to do the same for a pointer to the object. Instead of the custom string `MyObject as pointer` I get the default output:

```
x.cpp:22: Failure
Value of: pfoo1
Expected: has foo 0x8058330
  Actual: 0x8058320 (of type Foo*)
```

As a workaround I can dereference the pointers, but I'd like to know if there is a direct solution, which is to overload `PrintTo` on a pointer.

```
#include <gmock/gmock.h>

struct Foo { };

void PrintTo(const Foo& value, ::std::ostream* os) {
  *os << "<MyObject as object>";
}

void PrintTo(const Foo* value, ::std::ostream* os) {
  *os << "<MyObject as pointer>";
}

MATCHER_P(HasFoo, expected, "") { return false; }

TEST(Foo, Object) {
  Foo foo1, foo2;
  ASSERT_THAT(foo1, HasFoo(foo2));
}

TEST(Foo, Pointer) {
  Foo *pfoo1 = new Foo(), *pfoo2 = new Foo();
  ASSERT_THAT(pfoo1, HasFoo(pfoo2));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overloading as `void PrintTo(Foo* value, ::std::ostream* os)`? The `const` could make all the difference here.

Comment: Or maybe `PrintTo(Foo *const value, ::std::ostream *os)`?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @AndyG and @olaf-dietsche, the leading `const` should be removed. These work:

`Foo* value`

`Foo* const value`

And these does not:

`const Foo* value`

`const Foo* const value`

`const Foo*& value`